# How to change directory in my terminal using python

Tags: python, terminal, directory, download, macbookpro-touch-bar

The problem I have is that when I am in my terminal and I am at the base. I want to for instance change my directory to downloads I was wondering how I would do that because then after I would change my directory I would be able to access certain files in download and tell the computer that I want all the information in this file so my code can run properly.
Thank you

Comment: Are you in the interactive Python console? Or just in your terminal running bash, zsh whatever

Comment: Just open the files you want to open using their path, either absolute or relative. You can use the `os` module to help you construct paths and find files. You can use the `glob` module to grab files based on a pattern. Overall we need more details, and preferably some code in order to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use os;

```
os.system('cd ./Downloads')
```

Comment: even if OP is at the base, I think it could be better to be a bit more explicit `~/Downloads`, just in case